# Compiling c++ project through the command prompt

Tags: c++, xml, msbuild, visual-studio-2013

I'm having a hard time trying to figuring out what field to fill into an xml file I'm creating. I have been trying to follow 'Using MSBuild to Create a Visual C++ Project'(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293607.aspx) but I'm stuck on the xml part.
So the fields are:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <PlatformToolset>v120</PlatformToolset>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="main.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="main.h" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Targets" />
</Project>
```

The only part I know I have to change is the Item group portion to match all my .cpp and .h files. Are all the fields necessary? Can you give an example for the $(VCTargetsPath) in each of the Import Projects? This seems simple but only after the first time of doing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VCTargetsPath is property of the [toolset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383796.aspx), defined in registry. In your case, for `ToolsVersion="12"`, registry location would be `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\12.0`. Normally the toolset is configured automatically when you install appropriate SDK.

Comment: Am I suppose to fill in all the VCTargetsPaths with that directory? Is there a simpliar way to make a script on the command prompt using visual studios projects?

Comment: I found an easier way to pass in arguments. In Visual Studios I went to DEBUG->"project" Properties ->Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Command Arguments and filled in my inputs.

Comment: @dspaces1, the value of property VCTargetsPath is set when you install Microsoft Windows SDK (or Visual Studio, which includes Microsoft Windows SDK). It looks like you either don't have SDK installed, or perhaps you manually copied SDK files to the machine, or installation was somehow broken. I would start by fixing right SDK configuration, it would save you lots of time.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly never created a C++ project file with msbuild in the editor, always let vs do it for me and include/invoke the vcxproject file through my seperate custom build file... however, the TargetPath, is the directory of the configured targets for C++ of MSBuild, on my machine with vs 2013 installed its (configured to use the vc++ 12.0 tools): C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120.

These imports define the ClInclude task and all other C++ related tasks your tools support.

Comment: I Ultimate visual studios 2013 and can't find V120 or the directory in that same order.

Comment: It depends on the installation, and could also have something to do with me having 2012 installed prior... you can always do a find file for "Microsoft.Cpp.Targets" to find the location...